# 'killall -w' doesn't return after process has died

Tags: bash, unix, signals, linux-mint

In a shell script made in makefile, that is supposed to test the program, I have a "killall -QUIT -w chatty" line.
I've read the documentation, and it says that the killall -w returns only when the targeted process dies.

```
killall -QUIT -w chatty
HANDLER :       Recieved SIGQUIT
DISPATCHER :    Shutting down...
WORKER 0 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 1 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 3 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 6 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 2 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 5 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 7 :      Shutting down...
WORKER 4 :      Shutting down...
HANDLER :       Terminating
--------------------  CHATTY TERMINATIG  --------------------
# this is where the process terminates, and where the killall should 
# terminate too, but it remains active.

ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9094 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
21398 pts/2    00:00:00 make
21469 pts/2    00:00:00 killall
21471 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

What could be causing this problem?
I already checked for zombie processes, and it's not there.

Comment: The manpage clearly says `Note that killall may wait forever if the signal was ignored, had no effect, or if the  process  stays in zombie state.`

Comment: `I already checked for zombie processes`, how did you do that?

Comment: Signal wasn't ignored, the process actually terminated.  I already checked for zombies (with ps aux | grep 'Z'), and it's not there either. There's a 'ps' part that shows basically that the only processes active are makefile and killall.

Comment: Curious to know  the output for `killall -KILL -w chatty` As `KILL` can't be caught or ignored, this will give an insight about the underlying problem.

Comment: It terminated with the `killall -KILL -w chatty` . Then I tried the `-QUIT` again and it worked as inteded. I guess another process (not zombie) from previous tests on some other shell remained active, and I didn't terminate it. Thank you. I will be more careful about that. =)